# MAMP 3 not restarting after php.ini change

Tags: mamp-pro

Every time I make a change to php.ini through FILE > EDIT TEMPLATE > PHP > appropriate ini file, MAMP won't restart. I try using terminal to quit apache and mysql but it makes no difference and tells me they aren't running. I'm convinced there is some local non-mamp server running that is clashing with it but am not clever enough to work out what. My only solution is to restart my Mac (Macbook Pro Early 2013 running OSX 10.9.3) every time I make a change to php.ini. Which is not the end of the world but just a bit annoying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think after you make changes in php.ini and restart, there is another application who take your port 80 and apache can't start.

so to do a test you can close application like : skype, teamviewer,...
or change in there settings to not use this port.

or you can change the apache port to something like : 8094

Comment: Tried that (changing port) but then my localhost just doesn't work at all. Firefox tells me its unable to connect. But the restart (no php.ini change) worked fine, and I can see apache and mysql are running.

Comment: when you changed the port for example to 8094, you have to use in fiefox localhost:8094. anyway if now is workin that's good :)